# How to Get Required Columns data from a text File?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I need some help with reading my text file data

My Text File Data is like:

```
Name   start_date    end_date      dept_id
Rahul   1/28/2017    08/30/2017     1234
Ganesh  1/1/2016     08/28/2017     5678
```

I need to read this text file and do the operation (start_date -
end_date). I don't know how to take the required columns data directly in
python. I  am new to python, Can any one help me how to do to with
general python code and Pandas code for my output. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to take the start_date from the text file follow the code below:

```
    crs = open("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\sf.txt", "r")
    next(crs)
    for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in crs ):
        print(columns[1])
        print(columns[2])
```

this will get you the start_date and end_date

Comment: I tried to print row[1] and row[2].It's showing me error of list index out of range

Comment: can you post atleast 5 lines of your text file please

Comment: @Chetan V The code you have written using csv writer right. So can we write the same start_date - end_date using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

So you also wanted to use pandas, so in your case you can read your file data using pandas by following the code below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\sf.txt', sep="\t", header=0)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with usage of basic python code:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("Data.txt") as f:

    for line in f:

        if("Name" not in line):  # Skip Header

            data = line.strip().split()

            start_date = datetime.strptime(data[1], '%m/%d/%Y')
            end_date   = datetime.strptime(data[2], '%m/%d/%Y')

            print(end_date-start_date)
```

This produces result:

```
214 days, 0:00:00
605 days, 0:00:00
```

Hope it helps!